# Run PHP code after file is uploaded

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, phpspreadsheet

I'm using [JQuery File Upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) to upload an excel file to my server. I need to be able to use the [PHPSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) to then read the values from the excel file so that I can import them to the database. Both should happen in the same page. How can I use ajax to automatically run the PHPSpreadsheet code after file is uploaded?

Comment: we need to see how far you've gone, show some code please

Comment: Specifically, can you post the jQuery uploader code and the PHP code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

During upload, the client side include a URL to server side, (Upload Handler), this server side can include everything you want, for example at client side :

```
<form id="fileupload" action="../server/php/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

you specify the server side on form : `action="../server/php/"`

On the server side you can handle the upload, and when is finished you can do what you want with !

This is an official example for uploading, you may play with it until you succeed to upload a sample file, then you can implement it at your project :

Client side : https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/test/index.html

Server side : https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/tree/master/server/php

Good luck !

Comment: Thank you, so does the action="../server/php" get executed only after the file gets uploaded?

Comment: ur welcome, normally when the upload is complet (processed successfully) it will be avaible on server under the global $_FILES. then you can do what you want with. for example : if you want to read the file after the upload you can do smtg like : file_get_contents($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']);  ... in fact it depends on what you want to do with !

Comment: Oh alright. I just want the file to be processed by PHPSpreadsheet so that the data can be processed and used. I'll try it out and let you know if it works. Earlier I tried modifying the UploadHandler.php and it did not work as expected.